# Array filter with bound vs unbound function

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this code for getting the intersection of two arrays:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [2,3,4];
var intersection = a.filter(x => b.includes(x));
```

and I get `[2,3]` which is correct. But then I thought why not do this instead:

```
var binc = b.includes.bind(b);
var intersection = a.filter(binc);
```

and i get `[]`. Why? This works: `a.filter(x => binc(x))`, and `binc` and `x => binc(x)` returns the same value for every input. So what does filter do that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), you can see that `Array#includes` takes two arguments:

1. `searchElement`
2. `fromIndex` (the position in the array from which to search)

Because the way you call `binc`, it will get all the parameters a `Array#filter` callback gets:

1. `value` (fills `searchElement`)
2. `index` (fills `fromIndex` and makes your `includes` search fail)
3. `completearray`

So you would need to pass a callback to `Array#filter` that only passes the needed value into `Array#includes`, so that the `fromIndex` is not filled:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [2,3,4];
var binc = b.includes.bind(b);
var intersection = a.filter(x => binc(x));
```

Comment: Ah those darned extra arguments. Thanks. Was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

`filter` passes three arguments to the callback: `element`, `index` and `array`.
`includes` accepts two parameters: `searchElement` and `fromIndex`.

You can try to figure out yourself how the two interact with the additional parameters to result in a different outcome...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `includes(element, fromIndex)` method takes unnecessary second argument `fromIndex` when invoked in `filter(value, index, currArray)`. This breaks the `includes()` method execution.

To make your code work (just for studies, not for production), this approach can be used:

```
var oldIncludes = Array.prototype.includes;
Array.prototype.includes = function(element) { 
  //use only the first argument: the element
  return oldIncludes.call(this, element);
};

var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [2,3,4];

var binc = b.includes.bind(b);
var intersection = a.filter(binc);

console.log(interesection); //prints "[2, 3]"
```

Comment: Extending native prototypes might break other code, especially if you include third-party code that relies on a normally functioning `Array#includes`. Don't do this, unless you *really* know what you're doing.

Comment: @nils This code is provided only for studies. See the mention in the answer.